# RESTFUL POST with Python request to Glassfish Server

Tags: python, rest, glassfish

I'm having a difficulty trying to make a Python REST POST to a  webservice running on Glassfish. I have verified that POST works ok using CURL but having no luck with Python.

**Here is the CURL request that works ok.**

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1,"lastname":"smith"}' 
  http://192.168.0.20:8080/field1/resources/com.field1entity.field1
```

**Here is the Python code to make the POST request**

```
import urllib
import httplib2

def call():
http = httplib2.Http()

url = 'http://192.168.0.20:8080/field1/resources/com.field1entity.field1'

params = urllib.urlencode({"id":11111,"lastname":"oojamalip"})

response, content = http.request(url, 'POST', params, headers={'Content-type':'application/json'})
print "lets stop here to have a looksy at the variables"                               
print content

if __name__ == '__main__':

namesPage = call()
print namesPage
```

**Output from console,**

> Unexpected character ('l' (code 108)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
>    at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@18f494d; line: 1, column: 2]

Hope someone can shed some light on the problem.

thanks
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are url encoding the prams and then telling the server it is json encoded

```
import json

params = json.dumps({"id":11111,"lastname":"oojamalip"})
# then
response, content = http.request(url, 'POST', body=params, headers={'Content-type':'application/json'})
```

Comment: @om_kcin great welcome to SO. remember to "accept" the answer that works to get better response rates

Comment: Hi Phil, accepted answer ( i think) once again thanks for your help